# The TextInput onChange is one step behind

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

Kindly refer to the [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-lake-l40w8) for code.

Basically the input is lagging by one key press although I explicitly added the compute function in the callback of setState.

Edit: I understand the solution but I want to know why this is happening since I calling the function in the callback of setState.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

`onChangeText` method which gives value directly.

```
<TextInput onChangeText = {(value)=>{console.log(value)}} />
```

Comment: Hi, Can you explain why this happened in the first place?